# Using superclasses in QT Tests

Tags: qt, unit-testing, qttest

I'm trying to use a superclass to define common constructor, `initTestCase()`, `cleanupTestCase()`, `init()` and `cleanup()` code for tests.

```
class BaseTest : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

protected slots:
    void initTestCase();
    void init();
    void cleanup();
    void cleanupTestCase();
}

class Test1 : public BaseTest 
{
protected slots:
    void test1();
    void test2();
}

QTEST_MAIN(Test1)
```

Upon execution, the superclass slots (`initTestCase()`, `cleanupTestCase()`) are executed, but the subclass slots are ignored.

Is there a way to execute subclasses' tests in this context? How should common behavior be organized in QT Tests?

Edit: this has been fixed with the use of private slots, but there seems to be a repetition (nested execution), showing in the Test Results pane, relative to the plain output. Some sample code is posted.

parent.h:

```
#ifndef PARENT_H
#define PARENT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtTest>

class Parent : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

private slots:
    void initTestCase();
    void init();
    void cleanup();
    void cleanupTestCase();
};

#endif // PARENT_H
```

parent.cpp:

```
#include "parent.h"

void Parent::initTestCase() {}

void Parent::cleanupTestCase() {}

void Parent::init() {}

void Parent::cleanup() {}
```

testwithparent.h:

```
#ifndef TESTWITHPARENT_H
#define TESTWITHPARENT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtTest>
#include "parent.h"

class TestWithParent : public Parent
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

private slots:
    void test1();
};

#endif // TESTWITHPARENT_H
```

testwithparent.cpp:

```
#include "testwithparent.h"

void TestWithParent::test1() {
    Q_ASSERT(true);
}

QTEST_MAIN(TestWithParent)
```

Console output:

```
PASS   : TestWithParent::initTestCase()
PASS   : TestWithParent::test1()
PASS   : TestWithParent::cleanupTestCase()
Totals: 3 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 blacklisted
```

Test Results output:

```
Test summary: 6 passes, 0 fails. <-- double test count
Executing test case TestWithParent
    Executing test function initTestCase
    Executing test function test1
    Executing test function cleanupTestCase
    Executing test case TestWithParent <-- repetition
```

Comment: Use `private slots`, not `protected slots`.

Comment: This solved the parent execution problem. However, in this configuration the test subclass runs more than one time. I get output like:
```
    Executing test case Test1
        Executing test function initTestCase
        Executing test function test1
        Executing test function cleanupTestCase
        Executing test case Test1
            Executing test function initTestCase
            Executing test function test1
            Executing test function cleanupTestCase
```

Comment: Post more of your code and the output you're getting.  I can't reproduce the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Code has been posted.

Comment: Actually, the repeating behavior is independent of whether the test is subclassed or not. It is in the Test Results pane relative to the plain output.